# System.setProperty - Definir caminho para chromedriver

Tags: java, testes, selenium-webdriver

Estou começando a mexer com testes usando selenium e JUnit.
Preciso definir o caminho do chromedriver.exe. Gostaria de saber se tem como deixar o chromedriver.exe dentro da pasta do projeto e definir o caminho de uma forma que se outra pessoa baixe o projeto, pelo Github por exemplo, não precise redefinir o caminho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, faça da seguinte forma:

1º - Baixe o driver .exe e coloque dentro do seu diretório resources de test. Algo como: src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe.
Este diretório estará apto para ser commitado.

2º - Na sua classe de teste, onde você está tentando registrar a property, busque o exe por `this.getClass().getResource("chromedriver.exe").getPath();`. Ele ira buscar o executável dentro do resource de teste, local onde você armazenou o exe.

3º **Aproveite!**

---

4º - Se você estiver utilizando Arquillian + Maven, no arquivo de configuração do arquilian.xml é necessário as extensões:

```
<extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">${browser}</property>
    <property name="chromeDriverBinary">${chromeDriverBinary}</property>
</extension>
```

e as properties deverão ser registradas no pom.xml do Maven.

```
<properties>
    <browser>chrome</browser>
    <chromeDriverBinary>src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe</chromeDriverBinary>
</properties>
```

Comment: Testei da forma que sugeriu e estava dando NullPointerException. Mas deu certo ao utilizar this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver.exe").getPath(). Obrigado pela ajuda!